# Parse.com getParseObject Android class cast exception

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, classcastexception

I have a `Patient` object which has a pointer to a `Location` object.
I am doing this to parse the value after I receive the response from the server but I get this class cast exception. Anything I am missing here?

I checked the response and I can see the `Location` object for key primaryLocation.

```
public Location getPrimaryLocation() {
        Location location = null;
        try {
            location = (Location) getParseObject("primaryLocation"); 
        } catch(ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to
>   com.parsemodels.Location

Comment: What's `getParseObject` looking like these days?

Comment: Having the exact same problem...